# How to use BrowserStack with Symfony Panther

Tags: symfony, browserstack, symfony-panther

In the Symfony Panther [docs](https://symfony.com/blog/introducing-symfony-panther-a-browser-testing-and-web-scrapping-library-for-php) it states:

> Even if Chrome is the default choice, Panther can control any browser
> supporting the WebDriver protocol. It also supports remote browser
> testing services such as Selenium Grid (open source), SauceLabs and
> Browserstack.

But, there are no other documentation on how to do this.

How do you implement BrowserStack as a remote browser for Panther?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to create a new Panther client using a BrowserStack remote browser:

```
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Symfony\Component\Panther\Client;

$capabilities = array(
    "os"                       => "OS X",
    "os_version"               => "Monterey",
    "browser"                  => "Chrome",
    "browser_version"          => "latest",
    "name"                     => "Test",
    "build"                    => "Build 1.0",
    "browserstack.debug"       => true,
    "browserstack.console"     => "info",
    "browserstack.networkLogs" => true,
    "disableCorsRestrictions"  => true,
    "wsLocalSupport"           => true,
    "geoLocation"              => "US"
);
$caps = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
foreach ($capabilities as $key => $value) {
    $caps->setCapability($key, $value);
}
$client = Client::createSeleniumClient('https://[YOUR_BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME]:[YOUR_BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY]@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub', $caps);

$client->request('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com/');
```

You can see a list of capabilities here: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities

Comment: Thanks for the above!  This helped me figure out when using Symfony Panther with a local Docker Selenium Grid server.  $Client = Client::createSeleniumClient('http://'.self::$serverUrl, $capabilities);
In my instance, $serverUrl = '172.16.238.201:4444'.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to this -

https://github.com/symfony/panther/blob/main/examples/basic.php

https://stefanoalletti.wordpress.com/2018/07/02/symfony-docker-behat-browserstack-testing-your-app-like-a-boss/

https://symfony.com/blog/introducing-symfony-panther-a-browser-testing-and-web-scrapping-library-for-php

If you face any issue, please create a support ticket with them.